# Sorting queries with operations (Android - Parse.com)

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Treat the provided as pseudo-code.

```
 query.orderByDescending(0.25 * "likesCount" + 0.75 * "reblogsCount");
```

Why can't I run an operation on a query in such a way so as to sort a list by the weighted average of two different columns?

Do I really need to produce a new column, let's say "score", update it upon each like or reblog event, and then sort by that column?

Is there a way to achieve what I want in Parse in a few lines of code? If not, what is the alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can use subqueries.

Something similar to the following pseudocode:

```
 select * from (
    select field1, field2, 0.25 * likesCount + 0.75 * reblogsCount as sortField 
    from table
) order by sortField
```

---

You can also group your sort condition with parenthesis:

```
select * 
from table 
order by (0.25 * likesCount + 0.75 * reblogsCount)
```

Comment: I can see the value of this method from an SQL perspective, but I'm not sure this is possible in Parse because the column queried is referenced by a string, and you can't operate on strings.